# Invalid table ID - works in Bigquery UI, not in code

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running a simple query using the Java Bigquery API:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1e8ee0c9ba14bf1571e9

I execute this like:

```
bigquery.jobs().query(
  projectId, 
  new QueryRequest().setQuery(query).setUseQueryCache(false)
).execute();
```

Results in an error:

```
{
    "domain": "global",
    "message": "Invalid table ID \"qa_media.boardreader_review_20150418@1429779600388-\".",
    "reason": "invalid"
}
```

When I run this query in the UI it works:
https://bigquery.cloud.google.com

Any ideas?  This is very odd to me.

Thanks,
Luke

Comment: Could you try running a query without the time segment of the table, it will validate if the library does a bad escaping. Then the library might have a bug.

Comment: Can you share job IDs for a successful query job and a failed query job?

Comment: `{"jobId":"job_N7IK8Pao4-y0yGWo4ub6HiWgbrw","projectId":"pioneering-tome-782"}`

Comment: I also ran the query without the time segment (table decorator) and still failed.  I suspect it has something to do with the CASE statement because the query seems to work in Java when omit the field I am aggregating on.

{"domain":"global","message":"Invalid table ID \"qa_media.boardreader_review_20150418\".","reason":"invalid"}

Comment: @Danny, the previous jobId I posted came from a failed query, here is a job id from the same successful query using the UI:

Job ID: pioneering-tome-782:job_d1ofwsirFg-GQYJQeBx16hmK5vM

Comment: Hmm, both of those jobs appear to have succeeded.  I searched our query logs and couldn't find a job with the error message from your question, so I don't think we persisted a job within BigQuery for the failed query requests.  The specific error message is thrown when your table fails a regex parse, and it looks like the error might be that the dataset name, "qa_media", is trying to be parsed as part of the table name?  It's unclear to me what's going on, I'd suggest printing the query before you send it in your Java program and making sure it's identical to what you're running in the web UI.

Comment: I figured it out, this is not a bug.  The job that fails is not related to the query job.  It was an extract job that runs immediately after the query that was using the datasetId as part of the tableId in the configuration.  Thank you.